# isis redistribute bgp not working

Tags: bgp, is-is, redistribution

I am having trouble getting route redistribution into ISIS working. It works from ISIS to BGP, but I can't get the opposite to show up. I am using IOS-XR

Network has 3 routers:

A----B----C

A and B have an isis connection
B and C have a BGP connection

Router A has some 10.0.0.0 subnets that are shared with Rotuer B via ISIS. Router B is then passing these on to Router C with BGP, using the redistribute isis command.

Router C has a 192.168.56.0 subnet that is shared with Router B via BGP. Router B wants to share this with Router A via ISIS, but when I use the redistribute bpg command the route does not get added to the isis routes, and never shows on Router A.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Configuration for Router A (running IOS):

```
! trimmed, several interfaces with `ip router isis`
router isis
 net 49.0000.0000.0000.0000.00
```

configuration for Router B (running IOS XR):

```
router isis 1
 net 49.0000.1111.0000.0000.00
 distribute bgp-ls
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  redistribute bgp 65000 level-1
 !
 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  !
 !
 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/1
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  !
 !
!
router bgp 65000
 bgp router-id 10.255.0.101
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  redistribute isis 1
 !
 neighbor 10.100.0.1
  remote-as 65000
  address-family ipv4 unicast
```

Configuration for Router C (running IOS XR):

```
router bgp 65000
 bgp router-id 192.168.56.200
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  network 192.168.56.0/24
 !
 neighbor 10.100.0.2
  remote-as 65000
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  !
 !
```

On Router C running `show route bgp` lists all of the routes from ISIS on A and B.
On Router B running `show route isis` shows all of the ISIS provided routes I expect, and running `show route bgp` shows the 192.168.56.0 route that I expect from C
On Router A the 192.168.56.0 route does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default redistribution of IBGP into an IGP is disabled. To redistribute IBGP routes into an IGP, you need the command **bgp redistribute-internal**. Configuring this on B will inject BGP routes into ISIS.

```
router bgp 65000
 bgp redistribute-internal
```

More info here:https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/xr12000/software/xr12k_r3-9/routing/configuration/guide/xr12krc39_chapter1.html